# Sorting QList based on class property in Qt using Cpp

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qlist

I have a QList qList, I want to sort this based on the property "playerRank" in Players class.
The Players class is as shown below.

```
class Players
{
public:
    Players();
    int playerId;
    QString playerName;
    int playerRank;

    void setPlayerId(int id);
    void setPlayerName(QString name);
    void setPlayerRank(int rank);
};


#include "players.h"

Players::Players()
{

}

void Players::setPlayerId(int id)
{
    playerId = id;
}

void Players::setPlayerName(QString name)
{
    playerName = name;
}

void Players::setPlayerRank(int rank)
{
    playerRank = rank;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Ishra's answer is technically correct, but we can do better.

1. It's usually better to use the standard algorithms whenever possible
2. Make the parameters `const` so it works with containers to const objects too
3. No need for an inefficient "capture everything by copy" in the lambda

```
std::sort(qList.begin(), qList.end(), [](const Players& p1, const Players& p2) {  
    return (p1.playerRank < p2.playerRank);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can you **qSort** and pass a lambda as a comparator.

```
 qSort(qList.begin(), qList.end(), 
     [=] (Players& p1, Players& p2)->bool  
     {  
        return (p1.playerRank < p2.playerRank);  
     }
 );
```